# Waterflows simulation in Blender Game engine

Tags: esri-ascii-raster, blendergis

I have written an ESRI ASCII DTM importer for Blender and now I want to create something that can simulate the waterflows on that portion of terrain.

I have no idea on how to start, so does anybody know a previous project or a good tutorial on how to do some parts of this?

Comment: This is not necessarily GIS related. It should be on the blender SE site.

Comment: +1 for interesting application of GIS, however, are you saying you want to add relief/topography to an imagined landscape, or are you saying you want to visually and artistically represent moving water on screen? The first (inventing a landscape from scratch) could be accomplished using GIS tools and approaches, but second is more of an artistic/graphics problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent addon for Blender which allows you to import GIS-data. You can use it to import your DEM as a surface. You'll find it here:

https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

Then have a look at the Blender fluid simulation modifier:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Physics/Fluid

However, Blender is primarily a tool for visualisation. As such, I don't know how much you can trust the simulation in terms of its ability to predict real life outcomes. Moreover, since Blender is not a GIS, you will lose the spatial reference when importing your data.

[Edit] Sorry, I misread your post. I didn't realise you had written your own importer. If it has the functionality, you can skip to the fluid simulation modifier. And others who read this post and want to do something similar can use the link to the addon I posted.

Comment: I know, but I wanted something to create also a nice 3d simulation to watch, so I decided to use Blender for that purpose. Thanks!